# jQuery hide notification after x ms

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I found this script for warning message here: http://www.red-team-design.com/cool-notification-messages-with-css3-jquery

In the script it is set to hide the warning message after the click function

```
     $('.message').click(function(){              
              $(this).animate({top: -$(this).outerHeight()}, 500);
     });
```

So I added Timeout function in the hopes of closing it after x ms, but the 'timer' so to speak starts running as soon as the page is loaded.

```
    setTimeout(function(){hideAllMessages()},5000);
```

I want the timeout function to work every time the form is submitted and the drop message becomes visible (I am using a hidden iframe to submit the form and it is for stock, so repeated submits will be done on the same page).

I set up a **[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/asVAq/9/)** *jsfiddle*

Comment: move your timer to inside of the .animate complete callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to add it in your `showMessage` function like this:

```
function showMessage(type)
{
    $('.'+ type +'-trigger').click(function(){
          hideAllMessages();                  
          $('.'+type).animate({top:"0"}, 500);
          setTimeout(hideAllMessages,3000);     
    });
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/asVAq/20/)

**EDIT:** As suggested by James Montagne in the comments, you can use [`clearTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout) to prevent stocking timeouts if the user clicks around quickly.

Something like this (quick example, might not be production-ready):

```
var timeout = null;
function showMessage(type)
{
    $('.'+ type +'-trigger').click(function(){
          hideAllMessages();                  
          $('.'+type).animate({top:"0"}, 500);
          if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
          timeout = setTimeout(hideAllMessages,3000);     
    });
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/asVAq/23/)

Comment: Additionally, you may want to store the timeout id and use `clearTimeout` here as well.  If you click again before the timeout triggers you will see the messages hide too quickly.

Comment: @JamesMontagne Yep, added a quick example to my answer.

Comment: Thank a lot! I am new to jquery and I was stumped on that for at least 2 hours! The solution makes sense to put the timeout in the show message function. And thanks for also adding the clearTimeout, I definitely wouldn't have though of that!

Comment: @mcflause Happy to help. `setTimeout()` and `clearTimeout()` is actually Javascript, not jQuery, so be sure to familiarize yourself with Javascript as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the timeout after your animation is completed!

```
 $('.message').click(function(){              
          $(this).animate({top: -$(this).outerHeight()}, 500, function(){
               setTimeout(function(){hideAllMessages()},5000);  
          });
 });
```

Comment: This animation is to hide the message.  This would basically hide the messages after the message is hidden.  The timeout needs to be in the code which shows the message, not hides it.